# Got an unexpected keyword argument 'pzn'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm struggling with following problem:

fachbereich_detailview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pzn'

The error tells me that there is something wrong with my urls. If I change the last part of the url to int:test, it tells me that the unexpected keyword argument is test.

The query 'product = Products.objects.get(pzn="existingpzn")' is working fine (Tested with shell).

views.py

```
[...]
def fachbereich_detailview(request, pzn):

    context = {}

    try:
        product = Products.objects.get(pzn=pzn)
    except:
        return redirect('fachbereich')

    context['product'] = product

    return render(request, 'app/LoginArea/fachbereich_detailview.html', context)
[...]
```

urls.py

```
[...]
path('Produkt/<int:pzn>/', views.fachbereich_detailview, name='fachbereich_detailview'),
[...]
```

Html:

```
<a href="{% url 'fachbereich_detailview' product.pzn %}" class="small-text text-underline text-uppercase">Mehr erfahren</a>
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are setting `integer` in your url, but you are passing `string` to your view. Change your url to that:

```
path('Produkt/<str:pzn>/', ...),
```

Comment: Or just `<pzn>`.

Comment: You won't believe it, but unfortunately it does not work. The line looks like following:
    path('Produkt/<str:pzn>/', views.fachbereich_detailview, name='fachbereich_detailview'),

Comment: Also "Produkt/<pzn>/" does not work :(

Comment: @Nad3rk93 all options give the same error?

Comment: @NixonSparrow yeah..

Comment: @NixonSparrow Turned out I had a second view, which was not getting the argument. Deleted the one without the argument and now it works fine. Thank you!